# Ordering based on one value of many

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three SQL tables. Users, Registration Field Values, and Registration Fields.

| Name | zip code | favorite food |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sue | 55555 | sushi |
| Gary | 12345 | eggs |

Where zip code and favorite food are different registration fields.

The relationship is a user has many registration field values, and those values belong to the registration field.

I'm wondering how I can order my table based on a certain registration field. For example, selecting "favorite food", I would want "eggs" before "sushi".

This is confusing to me because I've only seen `ORDER BY` for an individual column or series of columns. I can't just `ORDER BY registration_field_value.value` because it needs to be based on only one of those registration fields.

This is like "ORDER BY field value where the associated field id is 'favorite food'", although I don't want to filter anything out.

I'm using Postgres if that makes a difference.

EDIT, adding a
[image: diagram]:

Comment: Show us some sample table data ordered in the wanted way.

Comment: You'll need to join the related table, and then using `ORDER BY` as you describe.

Comment: with "favorite food" ascending

| Name        | zip code    | favorite food
| ----------- | ----------- |--------------
| Gary        | 12345       | eggs
| Sue         | 55555       | sushi

with "favorite food" descending

| Name        | zip code    | favorite food
| ----------- | ----------- |--------------
| Sue         | 55555       | sushi
| Gary        | 12345       | eggs

It would look the same with zip code since the values would shake out that way.

Comment: I'm confused how a join will help because I'll still be in a situation where I'm saying "ORDER BY registration_field_value.value" which is ordering on all the values even though I want the order to only apply for certain registration fields.

Comment: I'm still not sure, I understand your table setup (maybe an ERM/ERD would help). But my guess it that you'll need a subquery to build your dataset out of the various tables, then a query on top of that to sort it.

Comment: @Pklong please check the answer if it fulfil your requirements.

Comment: @TheImpaler was essentially correct, although I had to first create a CTE for the join.

Answer (score 0):

You can use case to order based on specific value.

For eg:

```sql
ORDER BY
   CASE "favorite food"
      WHEN 'eggs' THEN 1
      ELSE 2
   END
```

The above query will move row with eggs to start and all other value will be moved to bottom.

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't help. I'm looking for a way to do this without hard-coding any values.

Comment: @Pklong how would you know that the user want's to view the records in particular order, are you getting the order from the user in any way that he want to suppose order the eggs first, then some other item and then some another item?

Comment: yes this is a table where the columns are sortable in ascending / descending order. The selection is given as the ID of the field.

Comment: @Pklong would it be based on single value from fields table by filtering out based on ID, can you update your question with same data and output